# cgi-bin within CentOS 6.5

Tags: linux, apache, centos, lamp

All,

I have got an LAMP server from Rackspace with CentOS 6.5 and I am following a document and I cannot find my cgi-bin folder. Apache is installed within LAMP. but I cannot find the cgi-bin.. Is there any commands I need to add to get this installed ? 
I am complete Newbie to LINUX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be under

```
            var/www
```

You could also try executing this

```
           find -name "*cgi-bin*"
```